# Not persistent id in Embedded Document in Mongoid 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, mongoid4

I use Mogoid first time (current beta with Rails-API 4 support). I use it to preserve user forms as one document with embedded documents. In update method in controllers I use this construct to create new card if returned card don't have id

```
params[:form_cards].andand.each do |card|
  card['form_card_fields'].andand.each do |field|
    if !field['id'].blank?
      @formField=@formCard.form_card_fields.find(field['id'])
    else
      @formField=@formCard.form_card_fields.create!
  end
end

if @form.save
  render json: @form, status: :created, location: @form
else
  render json: @form.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
end
```

It works in most cases. Unfortunatelly, sometimes something wrong happend and my created embedded document don't have persistent id, whenever I read it, result is different. After using

Example returned ID (each one is from different read operation for the same field)

```
536615c94d6163d0010a0000
536615d64d6163d0010b0000
536615dd4d6163d0010c0000
536615e84d6163d0010d0000
536616014d6163d0010e0000
```

My models looks like that:

```
class Form
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  embeds_many :form_cards
end

class FormCard
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  embeds_many :form_card_fields
  embedded_in :form

end

class FormCardField
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  embedded_in :form_card

end
```

I suppose it is some kind of persistence error but I can't find root cause...

I would be glad if whoever can help me cause it bugs me for three days

Answer (score 1):

add `cascade_callbacks: true` after the `embeds_many` or `embeds_one` so the models should look like the following

```
class Form
  ...
  embeds_many :form_cards, cascade_callbacks: true
  ...
end

class FormCard
  ...
  embeds_many :form_card_fields, cascade_callbacks: true
  ...
end
```

the `cascade_callbacks` allow running the callbacks of the embedded docs... so that persisting a parent persists it's embedded docs.